# Why is there a chloride ion in this 3D model?

Tags: protein-structure, covid-19, protein-protein-interaction, interactions, sars-cov-2

Here we have a 3D model of a sequence that match with this sequence
VVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIK
in Blast

the 3D structure is [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Structure/icn3d/full.html?&mmdbid=38995&bu=1&showanno=1)

Why is there a chloride ion in [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Structure/icn3d/full.html?&mmdbid=38995&bu=1&showanno=1) 3D model?

[image: screenshot of the 3D structure]

Answer (score 3):

It is a crystallisation artefact. Namely, the protein are placed in a condition where they fall out of solution without aggregating a gloop (as happens in most well in xstal trial) and to pack as a crystal they need to be placed nice and orderly. It is coordinated by water so is not relevant. A lot of structures have these —DMSO and ions are the most commonly.

Two footnotes.

- 1ZV7 is a crystal structure, *i.e.* solved by X-ray diffraction. A model is generally used to described an *in silico* model, such as those from Swissmodel, phyre, I-Tasser etc. These are generated *ab initio* (from scratch) or threaded (mapped on top of) against crystal/EM/NMR structures. For Covid I-Tasser has a [nice picture of its models](https://zhanglab.ccmb.med.umich.edu/COVID-19/).
- The best source of info about structures is the PDB. [RCSB PDB](https://www.rcsb.org/) is more commonly used, while [PDBe](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/) is more tricker to navigate (or used to be). Both have the same data, but are better for the extras than NCBI.